# Add Created date to Data in MS Access using Form_BeforeUpdate

Tags: ms-access, vba, insert-update

In customer master I want to save 4 information about when data was created, who created it, when was it updated and who updated it.

In the form, I have 4 text field. (Enabled property is set to FALSE, hence, users cannot edit it)

I am using Form's `BeforeUpdate` Event for updating the data.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    'Add Created by and Create Date
    If Me.CreatedBy = vbNull Then
        Me.CreateDate = Date
        Me.CreatedBy = CONST_User
    End If

    'Add Edited By and Date
    Me.EditedBy = CONST_User
    Me.EditDate = Date
End Sub
```

The problem, I am facing is, the above code updates `Me.EditedBy` and `Me.EditDate` but `Me.CreateDate` and `Me.CreatedBy` is left blank.

Not able to figure out, why `Me.CreateDate` and `Me.CreatedBy` doesn't get filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this line to:

```
If IsNull(Me.CreatedBy) Then
```